# Problems with writable folders

Tags: permissions, centos7

Im trying to install phpBB3 on my local centos7 server,
I have change the permission on the folder i need, but still i have errors.

```
Directory is not writable
To be able to install phpBB the cache/ directory needs to be writable.

Directory is not writable
To be able to install phpBB the store/ directory needs to be writable.

Directory is not writable
To be able to install phpBB the files/ directory needs to be writable.

File is not writable
To be able to install phpBB the config.php file needs to be writable.

Directory is not writable
It is recommended that the images/avatars/upload/ directory be writable for a better forum user experience.
```

I add this code in my terminal to see if the files is ok.

`ls -ld cache store files config.php images/avatars/upload`

It generate this :

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nfriberg nfriberg 40 Dec 19 22:16 cache
-rw-r--r--. 1 nfriberg nfriberg  0 Dec 19 23:32 config.php
drwxrwxr-x. 2 nfriberg nfriberg 40 Dec 19 22:16 files
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nfriberg nfriberg 40 Dec 19 22:16 images/avatars/upload
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nfriberg nfriberg 40 Dec 19 22:16 store
```

Hope someone can help me, im stuck now

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to change ownership of the file/folders to match the user account running your apache server... most likely that would be apache.

IE: `chown apache:apache config.php`